# Exception while taking screenshotSession ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?(TestNG)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am getting Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()? exception When runmode of anyone test case set as NO. I am using TestNg framework.

If Runmode of all test cases are Yes then it working fine.

I create one Java class for suite and create multiple inner class for individual test cases.

Below is my code.

```
    package com.smoke;

    import org.testng.SkipException;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    import com.util.TestUtil;

    @Listeners(com.listener.ListenerTestNG.class)

    public class Testxls extends TestSuiteBase {    
        @BeforeMethod
        public void checkTestSkip() {    
        APP_LOGS.debug("Checking Runmode of Testxls Test Case");    
      if(!TestUtil.isTestCaseRunnable(smoke,this.getClass().getSimpleName())) {
      APP_LOGS.debug("Skipping Test Case" + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " as runmode set to NO");
      throw new  SkipException("Skipping Test Case as runmode is set to NO");
  }
        }
        @BeforeTest
        public void testData() {
            try {
                objData=smoke.getTestCaseData("DataSheet", "Testxls");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(objData);

        }
        @Test()
        public void f() throws Exception {
            openBrowser();//Calling method to open browser
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            tearDown(); //calling method to quit browser

        }
    }

@Listeners(com.listener.ListenerTestNG.class)
class Testxls1 extends TestSuiteBase {

    @BeforeMethod
    void checkTestSkip()    {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        APP_LOGS.debug("Checking Runmode of Testxls1 Test Case");
        if(!TestUtil.isTestCaseRunnable(smoke, this.getClass().getSimpleName())) {
            APP_LOGS.debug("Skipping Test Case" + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " as runmode set to NO");
            throw new  SkipException("Skipping Test Case as runmode is set to NO");
        }
    }
    @BeforeTest
    void testData() {
        try {
            objData=suite_smoke.getTestCaseData("DataSheet", "Testxls1");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(objData);

    }
    @Test()
    void f() throws Exception {
        openBrowser();


    }
}
```

Please find Test case and data file screenshots.

[image]

any help is appreciated

Thanks
Vipin

Comment: The code is unreadable. Please format it.

Answer (score 0):

Whats implemented in TestSuiteBase? its mostly likely that you are using in same driver instance in all tests, so getting exception on quit in one test and still using in another test. check if you are using static webdriver.

better way is to create method which return webdriver instance as per your browser requirement and get it in starting of test, pass it to all methods in that test and quit finally.

Comment: Hi Murali, In TestSuiteBase we are checking suiteMode Yes No also TestSuiteBase extends the Our Base class which have all Prerequisites load xls, initialize method logs open browser login etc.  For webdrive we created global static reference variable.  After debugging i found the actual reason why this error occurred.   Reason is TestNg skipException  return failure status instead of Skip and if test case failed we took the screenshot but instance is already closed that-why it  through the exception. Actual issue from TestNg SkipException.